# How to write this regex code snippet right?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I am trying to get a UIWebView to display some text with images.
The text has some links inside of it so for example:

> "I once had a fish **`http://mysite.com/images/fish.jpg`**.
>   I also owned a little dog and a rooster **`http://mysite.com/images/dog.jpg`**"

would result in:

> **I once had a fish**

```
----------------------------------
|                                 |
|Fish Image From                  |
|http://mysite.com/images/fish.jpg|
|                                 |
|                                 |
----------------------------------
```

> **I also owned a little dog and a rooster**

```
----------------------------------
|                                |
|dog Image From                  |
|http://mysite.com/images/dog.jpg|
|                                |
|                                |
----------------------------------
--------------------------------------
|                                    |
|rooster Image From                  |
|http://mysite.com/images/rooster.jpg|
|                                    |
|                                    |
--------------------------------------



    NSMutableString *mutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body>%@</body>",string];

    NSString *pattern = @"http://.+\\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)";
    NSString *replacement = @"<br /><img style=\"width:100%;height:auto;\" src=\"$1\"/><br />";
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern           
                          options:0 error:NULL];
    [regex replaceMatchesInString:mutableString
                          options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, mutableString.length)
                          withTemplate:replacement];
```

But when I check on the result the image gets this: `<br /><img style="width:100%;height:auto;" src=""/><br />` and the link is gone.

Where the image has to be :

**Text...**
`<br /><img style="width:100%;height:auto;" src="http://mysite.com/images/fish.jpg"/><br />`

**Text...**

`<br /><img style="width:100%;height:auto;" src="http://mysite.com/images/dog.jpg"/><br />`

`<br /><img style="width:100%;height:auto;" src="http://mysite.com/images/rooster.jpg"/><br />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for `$1` to work properly you need to put the matched pattern inside a group, i.e., inside `()`. How about using the following pattern:

```
(http://.+\\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp))
```

Also from the pattern the `.+` part my eat the whole string. To make it less greedy it can be replaced with `.+?` or more correctly `\w.*?` to keep the effect of `+` in the original pattern.

Comment: It works with this: (http://.*(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)) , should I use this like that?

Comment: @Ted Well this is very engine dependent. But if you find it not working with other programming languages in future, consider using `.*?` instead of `.*` alone.